# visual studio installer error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with the Visual Studio 2017 installer. After the bootstrapper finishes extracting it just disappears. When I look at the log file this is what I get:

```
[1/9/2018, 21:42:20] === Logging started: 2018/01/09 21:42:20 ===
[1/9/2018, 21:42:20] Executable: D:\vs_community__592033820.1511985053 (1).exe v15.5.27130.2020
[1/9/2018, 21:42:20] --- logging level: standard ---
[1/9/2018, 21:42:20] Directory 'C:\Users\Edy\AppData\Local\Temp\ef86a27e9711ba14b47f0fe666f4f8ea\' has been selected for file extraction
[1/9/2018, 21:42:20] Extracting files to: C:\Users\Edy\AppData\Local\Temp\ef86a27e9711ba14b47f0fe666f4f8ea\
[1/9/2018, 21:42:20] Extraction took 266 milliseconds
[1/9/2018, 21:42:20] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline ' '
[1/9/2018, 21:42:25] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[1/9/2018, 21:42:25] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0xe0434352
[1/9/2018, 21:42:25] === Logging stopped: 2018/01/09 21:42:25 ===
```

Can someone help me? I looked for 2 days for a fix and nothing worked

Comment: Sounds like your system has been locked down. Try to use the offline installation steps, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio#create-an-offline-installation-folder

Comment: I tried with the offline installation but still doesn't work. In the log files appears the exact same thing